# How do you exit from Edit Style in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Once you enter into Edit Style.. Edit Current from the Format menu how do you return to the regular Designer mode where you can edit individual components? I've looked all over the program and google'd everything I could think of but can't figure it out. I have to close the XAML file and re-open it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

View -> "Other Windows" -> "Document Outline" -> Click the "Up" indicator

[image]